# Why Array.from(classList)[0] = "className" not work

Tags: javascript, arrays

Html code

```
<div class="container color-blue">
        <h3>HI I am a container</h3>
    </div>
```

js code

```
let div =document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
let a = div.classList;
// here is a is an object 
// so I use array.from(a) to turn in into array 
Array.from(a)[0] = "font";
```

"arrays are mutable and array can be chnaged"
but it not replacing my container that is the first item of array with font

Comment: It's creating and changing a _new_ array.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Try `div.classList.add('font')`?

Comment: You are creating a new array with that from call

Answer (score 2):

`Array.from` will create a *new array* from `classList` which is an instance of [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList).

If you must remove the first item do

```
let div =document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
let a = div.classList;
a.remove(a.item(0))
```

You can then just add the item you need

```
a.add("font");
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother.Now I know Array.from creates a new array not change the original array. Thank you so much from again